# Loops in Python : how to apply same set of code in a loop

Tags: python, loops

Thank you for all your help in my previous questions.
Now it leads me to my final and most difficult task. Let me break it down:

I have a file named:
"PCU1-160321.csv"

Then I run the following codes (see below) that helps me to do all sorts of things I need to do.

This leaves me to the most difficult task which is to do again and again the same set of code (see below), to other other 23 files, named:

PCU**2**-160321.csv
PCU**3**-160321.csv
...
PCU**24**-160321.csv

Eg. I wish to call df2 for PCU2-160321.csv, df3 for PCU3-160321.csv etc. (Hence, loop...)

Or is there a better looping method?

Below I attach the visualisation:
[image]

Thank you very much.

UPDATE:
I did try something like this , but it didn't work...
[image]

```
#Assign file names
file1 = 'PCU1-160321.csv'
file_out1 = file1+'15min.csv'

#Read csv file and assign header
df1 = pd.read_csv(gdrive_url+file1+'.csv', sep=';', names=['Date','Time_Decimal','Parameter','Value'])

#To split the Time_Decimal column and concatenate the second decimals back into Time column, and rearrange the column order
df1[['Time','DecimalSecond']] = df1.Time_Decimal.str.split(".",expand=True)
df1 = df1[['Date', 'Time', 'DecimalSecond', 'Parameter','Value']]

#Split AM and concatenate DecimalSecond
df1[['Time', 'AMPM']] = df.Time.str.split(" ", expand=True)
df1 = df1[['Date', 'Time', 'AMPM', 'DecimalSecond', 'Parameter','Value']]
df1['Time'] = df1['Time'].map(str) + '.' + df1['DecimalSecond'].map(str) + ' ' + df['AMPM'].map(str)
df1['Timestamp'] = df1['Date'].map(str) + ' ' + df1['Time']
df1 = df1[['Timestamp', 'Parameter','Value']]

#Assign index and set index as timestamp object
df1['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Timestamp'])
df1 = df1.set_index('Timestamp')

#Assigning parameters I want to filter out of the df above.
Parameter1 = 'DCA_L_1'
Parameter2 = 'DCA_L_2'

#Filtering based on the variables defined above, contains whatevr parameter I need.
df1_param1 = df1[df1['Parameter'].str.contains(Parameter1)]
df1_param2 = df1[df1['Parameter'].str.contains(Parameter2)]

#Renaming the columns header
df1_param1.columns = ['Par1','Val1']
df1_param2.columns = ['Par2','Val2']

#Obtain exact name of parameter into a string, then we use this for the new df top row
par1 = df1_param1.head(1)['Par1'].values[0]
par2 = df1_param2.head(1)['Par2'].values[0]

#Downsampling 15 mins
df1_param1 = df1_param1.resample('15min').mean()
df1_param2 = df1_param2.resample('15min').mean()

#Concatenating all the dfs - except empty df, df_ppc_param4
df1_concat = pd.concat([df1_param1, df1_param2], axis=1)

#Select Values
df1_concat = df1_concat[['Val1','Val2']

#Rename columns to the new df_concat
df1_concat.columns = [par1,par2]

#To save output as csv
df_concat.to_csv(gdrive_url_out+file_out+'.csv', index=True)
```

Comment: Do you need 24 different dataframes? Are you going to be combining the all once you've read in all the files,l?

Comment: Basically I will have 24 csv files. Every one csv file, I will have cherry pick 2 specific unique parameters. At the very end, only one output file with 48 columns or unique parameters. The code I have above works only for one file. I was thinking of putting a loop of the set of code... Any other idea you may have? Thank you.

Comment: It should be straightforward to adapt the current code to process each file but what would you want to do with the data from each file after it has been processed?

Comment: After i got that one output file, i will do further processing in excel. Yeah.. very noob with loops